# How can I consume multiple parameterized web api using mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am consuming **web api** using **MVC controller** which require **two parameters**. On the basis of parameters data will be return in Json format. How can I consume api with two parameters? 
api-url: http://www.example.com/apiname/methodname/
Parameters:
param1
param2

api-key details:
api-key: x-api-key
api-key value: apikeyvalue

example : http://www.example.com/apiname/methodname/param1/param2

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"apiurl");  

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "apikeyvalue");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //HTTP GET
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("GetAttendances");

            responseTask.Wait();



            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MonitoringCallsViewModel>>();
                readTask.Wait();
            }
            else //web api sent error response 
            {
                //log response status here..

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
}
```

}

Comment: Do provide some code. For instance, your controller's action you mean to consume. Secondly, elaborate on where you are planning on consuming form (language and the framework).

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I have updated question. Brief description provided. Please go through it.

Comment: if you are sure your API takes parameters in URL, just use `$"GetAttendances/{param1}/{param2}"

Answer (score 1):

I don't get much details from your explanation but you can consume an api endpoint in 2 ways. First one is that the api gets the parameters through query and you can set those variables to the query (request url) like below.

```
    public static string YourUrlSetterFunc(string baseUri, int id, int categoryId)
    {
            return $"{baseUri}/endpoint-route?firstParam={firstParam}&secondPram={secondPram}";
    }
```

Or you can set those variables which are not taken from url and they called FormData trough appropiate HttpClient method. Example shown below.

```
var serializeObject = _jsonSerializer.Serialize(YourClassThatHoldsParams);
using (var requestContent = new StringContent(serializeObject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                using (var responseMessage = await PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent))
                {
                    response = _jsonSerializer.DeSerialize<TV>(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }
            }
```

In this way, you can read JSON response as string and then deserialize it to the object yoıu want. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Hasan. I have updated my question. Please go through it. Let me know code is proper or not.

Comment: It looks okay to me. You just need to configure url as specified and send it via HttpClient as you did.